# Office laptops has two accounts one for employee and another named admin

Tags: software-industry

Why does any office create two accounts on office laptops? 
One on employee name and another on admin/office/company name.
What is the purpose of it?

Comment: Probably for maintenance.  Don't use the machine for anything you don't want others to see or know about.

Comment: In addition to the other reasons, backup. In an organization with hundreds of computers, that computers can magically transform themselves into bricks/doorstops is a far too regular occurrence for IT.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is so that support can access your computer without needing to sign in on your profile. They may need to do this for any number of reasons, troubleshooting, software installation, updating etc,.

It's routine in many networks, particularly those where normal users do not have full admin rights to their machines. But a good idea even when they do, user profiles can become corrupted creating issues signing in and a host of other potential problems which can much more easily be fixed if there is an existing local profile which can be used.

Comment: To add to this, It could also be the account used to setup the computer which will have full admin access rights. If you are a local user, it can show you all possible accounts on the computer.

Answer (score 3):

That is also how I set up my personal machines - for normal use admin level access is not necessary.

This limits the errors I can make as an “ordinary” user and if I need to install something I just enter the admin password when asked.

Comment: both admin and employe account are provided with admin access.

Comment: That’s their / your choice - whether it is sensible is a different question... I don’t need admin level access 24/24...